# turn a mixed list into a string, keep quotes only for strings

Tags: python, sql, string, list, methods

I would like to go from this list:

```
my_list = [u'a','b','c',1,2,3]
```

...to this string, which maintains the quotes (for creating a sql statement):

```
my_string = "'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3"
```

This method works, but it sure is ugly!

```
my_string = str(my_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('u','')
```

Is there a nicer way?  What's wrong with heaping up the replaces - that *can't* be right!?

Comment: Don't handle quoting yourself. Use SQL parameters instead and have the *database adapter* worry about this instead.

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer: you should NOT be preparing SQL using plain string manipulation! use a library appropriate for the database you are using to prepare statements.**

for your edification (note this doesn't properly format unicode literals, you can feel free to replace `repr` with a function with a special case for unicode):

```
my_string = ', '.join(repr(x) for x in my_list)
```

Comment: it prints `"u'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3"`