# pasting a mixed list and keep quotes on strings

Tags: r

This is basically the R equivalent of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953959/turn-a-mixed-list-into-a-string-keep-quotes-only-for-strings).

I have a list of mixed elements:

```
l = list(-1, "quicksort", NULL)
```

And I want to turn it into a string:

```
string = '-1, "quicksort", NULL'
```

But I can't figure out how to easily keep the quotes inside the string without putting ALL elements in quotes:

```
paste(l, collapse = ", ") # WRONG
# "-1, quicksort, NULL"

paste(shQuote(l), collapse = ", ") # WRONG
# '"-1", "quicksort", "NULL"'
```

I have a solution, but it seems clumsy:

```
paste(lapply(l, function(x) if(class(x) == "character") shQuote(x) else x),
  collapse=", ")
# '-1, "quicksort", NULL'
```

Is there a simpler (i.e. no `if` statement) solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deparse()` the list and then remove the unwanted characters.

```
gsub("list|[()]", "", deparse(l))
# [1] "-1, \"quicksort\", NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution ended up being

```
paste(lapply(l, deparse), collapse = ", ")
```

Which bypasses the need for `gsub` stuff and supports any type of list element. I think it's a bit more readable too.